# Are public variables faster than using getters and setters?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

I am writing a custom physics engine for a game that I am making, my physics object class has tons of variables (distance, velocity, acceleration, mass, gravity, force, impulse duration etc....). Will creating a setter and getter function for each of these variables impact performance?
(There will be at least 100 instances of this class at a given time)

Also should I create setters and getters? I heard public variables are really bad practice but there are a lot of variables, can this be an exception?

Comment: _"I heard public variables are really bad practice "_ Where did you hear that?

Comment: There are no dedicated getters and setters in C++, just plain member functions.

Comment: Try it. Measure. Benchmark. And think about your design! While the performance impact will be non-existent is there really a difference between a public member variable or public getter/setter functions? What do basic OO principles say about encapsulation? Is a member variable *really* encapsulated if you have getter/setter functions?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTS7JTud1qQ, 2:15

Comment: @VishnuShankar I don't see any reasoning from that video why the guy creates getter/setter functions there. There's absolutely no benefit over a public variable `name`.

Comment: Use getters and setters when you wish to encapsulate the implementation. For example, a value that may be provided by wither a variable or a calculation of other values.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm not sure the _encapsulation_ argument works; despite the _function_ being the same in an _implementation_, there is indeed an _encapsulation_ difference.  The usage `foo->x` binds you to a specific variable; you may change the type of variable, but that's about it.  The usage `foo->x()` releases this binding; now you can change _how to get x_; caching, computing, make getting x throw exceptions in cases, etc without changing the use.

Comment: The answer is: It depends. Let say you have a Shape instance with a `Point getPoint()` where it will actually create a `Point` instance from different internal values. This is a good getter example. But do you really need a getter for `int Point::getX()` or can we just call `myShape.getPoint().x` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Will creating a setter and getter function for each of these variables impact performance? (There will be at least 100 instances of this class at a given time)

Probably no. Theoretically yes, but in practice, the cost of calling an extra function to get a particular value is negligible. The only way it will impact performance is if you end up calling these methods *all the time* (say ... 50000 times per second).

> Also should I create setters and getters?

Probably no. Good OO design follows a guideline called "tell, don't ask". Usually you should see what operations you need these variables for, then either implement those operations in the class, or implement them in a class that has access, or use a different model (visitor pattern comes to mind).

> I heard public variables are really bad practice but there are a lot of variables, can this be an exception?

Having public variables is not bad practice. Having public variables when you have invariants on them, is bad practice.

For example, if you have a variable measuring the weight of an object, you will want to make sure this cannot be set to an invalid value (such as a negative amount, or a ridiculously large amount). If you make the variable public, you will either have to check the value you set everywhere in client code where you modify it, or give up on validating that value.

Both are bad, as they are errors that couldn't exist if you had a propper setter, with validation.

In short, having public variables is only acceptable if you have no invariants on them.

Considerations:

- use public variables, if setting any value permitted by the variable type is OK, at any point (you have no invariants)
- use private variables if you have invariants.
- use public methods to define operations, not "access to internal variables".
- design your public API in terms of *operations you want to perform when you look at it from the client code*, not in terms of *variables present in the internal implementation*.

In this context, getters and setters make sense some times (rarely), but not because you have the variables in the class.

- getters and setters are a symptom of trying to solve a problem in the wrong place: if you have an operation X in class A that uses variables from class B, then you should probably define operation X in class B, then call it from class A.

Comment: The considerations are brilliant, setting any value to the variables in my class will not break anything, I will go with public variables.

Comment: "in practice, the cost of calling an extra function to get a particular value is negligible" - especially if the optimizer does its job of removing the function abstraction (inlining) properly; in which case it will be zero.

Answer (score 9):

> Will creating a setter and getter function for each of these variables impact performance?

As for simple getter/setter functions, they can be usually inlined by the compiler so there won't be a performance impact.

> Also should I create setters and getters? I heard public variables are really bad practice

Public variables aren't inherently a bad practice, though usually you want to encapsulate your data in a class, especially if there are calulations applied on them.

Classes which only provide getter/setter functions are useless, these can usually simply replaced with a `struct` with all public variables.

Comment: I was just typing an answer with the same thoughts. :] Sometimes I'm surprised how fast you are folks.

Comment: Classes which only provide getter/setter functions can be somewhat useful when debugging: you can set a breakpoint on an accessor function to help track down where that mysterious change in value is coming from.

Comment: And I believe you can use the aggregate initialization on public variable as well.

Comment: Classes that provide only accessor methods can evolve into classes that do more than that without breaking anything in the process. Simple structs can't.

Comment: @PeteBecker If you need that, your system design probably has other problems.

Comment: @PeteBecker don't you think it's bad if you end up with "debugging" code on the production line?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There are a lot of calculations performed on these variables, but these variables are also constantly being changed by other classes and if I make getters and setters for each of these variables there will be at least twenty extra functions. Do i really need to encapsulate them?

Comment: @VishnuShankar An another approach is using public variables, and an `update()` function, which you can call and perform your calculations with the new data.

Comment: @VishnuShankar if your values are being modified by other classes, they are **not encapsulated**. Wrapping the data members in getters/setters doesn't change that

Comment: @plasmacel Thanks, that is exactly what I am doing! I think the public variables are ok to have.

Comment: @Caleb There's stuff (i.e. merely used for de-/serialization) where I'm pretty sure that there won't be any evolvement besides adding more data members.

Comment: @Caleth The variables are modified by classes that inherit properties from this class. Example Box, Arrow, Ball etc....

Comment: @PeteBecker Doesn't your debugger support watches and break on certain variable changes?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's fine, but it doesn't justify the blanket statement that *classes which provide only getter/setter functions are useless*. You don't *always* have to use encapsulation, but that doesn't mean it's not useful.

Comment: @VishnuShankar _"There are a lot of calculations performed on these variables"_ In this case you should encapsulate them, yes. But as I mentioned if you have a simple getter function there, won't be a performance impact, since the compiler can inline it. I suppose that setter functions need to trigger a recalculation.

Comment: @Caleb in which case would you want to create a class which provide only getter/setter versus plain simple `struct`?

Comment: @Caleb _" but that doesn't mean it's not useful."_ I din't say so finally.

Comment: @VishnuShankar what I mean is that "Encapsulate" does not mean "write a getter and a setter", almost the opposite

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think I will go with plasmacel's approach of update() function, that way I can tell when to perform the calculation and not mess up any variables. I have already implemented an update function, so I think I am going to stick with public variable instead of twenty getter and setter functions.

Comment: @Vishnu I also believe that's the best option in your case.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - sure, you can use watchpoints, etc. But that's not the same as breaking on **every** modification of a field in **every** object of that type.

Comment: @Ceros -- huh? Accessors typically get inlined in production code; there's no extra "debugging" code. But I don't want to debate what might be the best approach in a particular application; I made a **general** statement about **possible** utility in response to a sweeping asssertion that this is **useless**. Don't take this down the rabbit hole.

Comment: @PeteBecker I was talking more about the extra text only for "debugging" not about the performance/compiler optimization. Anyways, I guess there is no right nor wrong answer for this

Answer (score 0):

simply public variable violates OO design principles, but getter setter does not, That why we need to the user always getter and setter